# liferay : When exactly to override doHelp and doEdit methods of GenericPortlet?

Tags: liferay

I see that when we extend this GenericPortlet class, there are methods like doHelp, doEdit, doView and processAction.

When I had gone through the tutorials on internet, I see that people using GenericPortlet don't bother to override the two methods doEdit and doHelp.

Please tell me, when and in which scenarios do we need to override these two methods (doEdit and doHelp), Is there any website that allows users to have these behaviours ??

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These 3 methods are part of the Portlet API ([JSR168](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/review/jsr168/index.html)) .

The 'doHelp' method is conceptualized to show the user helpful information about how to use the portlet and it is render method implemented for HELP mode.

The 'doEdit' method is conceptualized for portlet configuration to personalize the portlet i.e. to specify user preferences and it is render method implemented for EDIT mode.

In real production this proposal isn't really optimal, hence portlet container's like Liferay have made their own concept for these things and don't use 'doHelp' and 'doEdit' methods.

For portlet configuration as used in liferay see this [wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+Add+Configuration+Page+to+a+Plugin+Portlet).